# Drupal views multiple sort criteria

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have multiple content types in drupal and they both use different date fields. One is using blog_date and second post_date. When I merge them in one view and try to sort by multiple sorting criterias, they are always sorted by the first one. I.e. if I sort by blog_date first, all blog type posts will appear and only after that post type posts will follow with their sorting criteria.

Is it possible to merge those two data fields into one and then sort nodes globally?

Answer (score 0):

I found many possible solutions and summarized them here: https://drupal.org/node/2133879

However, this is a simple solution that I'd recommend:

In a custom module use the hook_views_query_alter() function to alter the sort criteria to use CASE ... WHEN to add a conditional in the orderby condition. A good example is shown here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'view_name') {
    // Completely replace current orderby
    $query->orderby = array(" CASE
        WHEN node_data_field_dates_field_dates_value THEN node_data_field_dates_field_dates_value
        WHEN node_data_field_event_dates_field_event_dates_value THEN node_data_field_event_dates_field_event_dates_value
    END ASC ");
  }
}
?>
```

Example source: https://drupal.org/comment/6323288#comment-6323288